# Html/javascript validation failing

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Does anyone know why this javascript isn't working ? Its returning the field is empty when its not

The html i'm using on the form is:

```
 onsubmit="return validate_form ( );" method="post" name="AddPTR"
```

And the javascript is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate_form ( )
{
valid = true;

if ( document.forms.AddPTR.PTR2.value == "" )
{
    alert ( "Please fill in the PTR box." );
    valid = false;
}

return valid;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Where's the HTML of the input field?

Comment: Probably you are getting a null reference somewhere in the following chain: `document.forms.AddPTR.PTR2.value`. Also when declaring a local variable in javascript it is a good practice to put a `var`. So `var valid = true;`. This avoids *polluting* the global scope.

Comment: Should work fine, see example: http://jsfiddle.net/ezDR4/

Answer (score 5):

[`document.forms`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DOM-Level-1-19981001/level-one-html.html#attribute-forms) is a standard DOM property that holds an array with the `<form>` tags in the document.

If you want to access the `AddPTR` form, you can do it in two ways:

- If you've only got one `<form>` in the document, or know the order they are in, you can access the array by index: `document.forms[0]`.
- If you want to get the `<form>` by its name `AddPTR`, you can get it from the `document.forms` property accessing it as an associative array: `document.forms["AddPTR"]`. This approach has the advantage of being independent from the document layout.

See this W3C link for some information on how to access associative arrays: [Objects in JavaScript: Objects as associative arrays](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Objects_in_JavaScript#Objects_as_associative_arrays)

Comment: Hi, I've just tried using    if ( document.forms["AddPTR"][PTR2].value == "" ) And still no luck, Any idea ?

Comment: Just use `document.forms["AddPTR"].PTR2.value == ""` or `document.forms[0].PTR2.value == ""`. You could also do `document.forms["AddPTR"]["PTR2"].value == ""`. Remember to use a string for the key when accessing the array as an associative array.

Comment: Hello, The 1st and 3rd option you suggested show the please fill in field message even if field is filled in, the 2nd suggestion doesn't show the message if empty or filled

Comment: Which browser are you using? Check if it works for you in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VRQvH/2/)

Comment: So, check if you've got the same structure in your page. Is `PTR2` the `name` of an `<input>` element that is a direct child of the `<form>`? Debug which access in that sentence is failing.